# Set message custom properties when rejecting message

Tags: node.js, azureservicebus

I have this simple application that uses [node-amqp10](https://github.com/noodlefrenzy/node-amqp10) to read messages from some subscriptions and process/accepts or rejects messages due to some error that might happen.
My question is, is it possible for the consumer to set any additional property into the message when rejecting? (like DeadLetterError)

I've thought the receiverLink.reject would get the error parameter and set into the message automatically, but maybe this is not even possible (consumer setting properties into the message)

[image: Service Bus Custom Properties]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Azure Service Bus based on the tag in your question. If you use [`@azure/service-bus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/azure/service-bus) package instead, you have the option of updating properties of the [message](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/@azure/service-bus/servicebusmessage). Also while dead lettering you can provide `deadLetterReason` and `deadLetterErrorDescription` like below:

```js
async function receiveMessage() {
  // If receiving from a subscription you can use the createReceiver(topicName, subscriptionName) overload
  const receiver = sbClient.createReceiver(queueName);

  const messages = await receiver.receiveMessages(1);

  if (messages.length) {
    console.log(
      ">>>>> Deadletter the one message received from the main queue - ",
      messages[0].body
    );
    // Deadletter the message received
    await receiver.deadLetterMessage(messages[0], {
      deadLetterReason: "Incorrect Recipe type",
      deadLetterErrorDescription: "Recipe type does not match preferences."
    });
  } else {
    console.log(">>>> Error: No messages were received from the main queue.");
  }

  await receiver.close();
}
```

For more details, refer [Azure Service Bus client library for Javascript](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus).

Comment: Actually I'm using `node-amqp10` package, this project came before `@azure/service-bus` was at a stable version. Since I'm thinking about using this Microsoft package in another project that still uses `azure-sb`, I'll try migrating `node-amqp10` after.

Comment: I'll create a POC to test what you've posted and let you know

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear what package I was using because I can't create tags with my current privileges

Comment: Sorry the delay, it worked exactly as I wanted to. Maybe it's time to move to this package. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, is it possible for the consumer to set any additional
> property into the message when rejecting? (like DeadLetterError)

No, you can't. I know what you want to do, But the method of the basic module '`@azure/service-bus`' is not designed as you think.

For NODE.JS, it is `deadLetterMessage(ServiceBusReceivedMessage, DeadLetterOptions & [key: string]: any)`.

JavaScript reference API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/service-bus/servicebusreceiver?view=azure-node-latest#deadLetterMessage_ServiceBusReceivedMessage__DeadLetterOptions____key__string___any_

It don't allow you to add custom properties.

But if you using C#, then it is possible:

`DeadLetterAsync(String, IDictionary<String,Object>)`

C# API reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.queueclient.deadletterasync?view=azure-dotnet

In short, for NODE.JS you can only change the description of the dead-letter message, but can't add custom properties.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear what package I was using because I can't create tags with my current privileges, but it is the [node-amqp10](https://github.com/noodlefrenzy/node-amqp10)

Comment: Actually it worked as I expected following the @krishg answer. The `deadLetterMessage` second parameter sets the message properties.